# 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT When i upload bunch of images

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passage

I have application in which i uploads multiple images using zip file.

It is working fine in my local system and also working fine on server if I upload only 2 images but when I am trying to upload more than 20 images in a single zip it gives me following error :

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)**

I am using centos + apache + passenger on server.

**environment**

OS: Centos7

ruby: 2.2.3 installed with rvm

passenger 5.5.0

rails: 4

PostgreSQL: latest version

apache installed with passenger

If you have any solution please answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, server need continues connection for file or image upload, but when file size is large and if you don't need to do any processing on file then we need to set background job for same.

So, server upload that file gradually and not throw any kind of error like 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT.

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: But i want to upload all images at a time.User will wait till upload that's fine for me.

Is there any other solution than background job ?

Comment: I don't think so,but you set synchronous job for continues images upload.

Comment: if you don't want to set background job take a look http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/04/10/rails-and-large-large-file-uploads-looking-at-the-alternatives/